Transitioning from iOS Development to Solana
I have been a full-time iOS Developer since 2015, and recently, I became interested in Solana app development.
To get started, I am currently learning Rust from the official book. I have read that developers should learn JavaScript/TypeScript for building clients and interacting with the blockchain. However, I am considering leveraging my existing iOS skills to create clients, so I can focus more on on-chain development initially.
Is this a good approach, or should I prioritize learning JavaScript/TypeScript right away? Can I postpone learning these languages and concentrate on on-chain development while using my iOS knowledge for client-side logic?

If you're focusing on iOS development and interacting with the Solana blockchain using Rust and SolanaSwift, you'll likely only need JavaScript/TypeScript for web-based applications. So, for now, you should be good to go without diving into JavaScript/TypeScript.

Leverage your iOS skills to develop client applications, concentrate on learning Rust for Solana's on-chain development, and consider learning JavaScript/TypeScript later for additional client-side interactions and community tools.
here are quick ways to get you started SolDev
